# How to pass each row as an argument to R script from Tableau calculated field

Tags: r, tableau-api, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do sentiment analysis on a table that I have.

I want each row of string data to be passed to the R script, but the problem is that Tableau is accepting only aggregate data as params for:

```
SCRIPT_STR(
  'output <- .arg1; output', [comments]
)
```

This gives me an error message:

```
# All fields must be aggregate or constant.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Tableau and R Integration](http://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-5313) documentation:

> Given that the SCRIPT_*() functions work as table calculations, they
>   require aggregate measures or Tableau parameters to work properly.
>   Aggregate measures include MIN(), MAX(), ATTR(), SUM(), MEDIAN(), and
>   any table calculations or R measures. If you want to use a specific
>   non-aggregated dimension, it needs to be wrapped in an aggregate
>   function.

In your case you could do:

```
SCRIPT_STR(
  'output <- .arg1; output', ATTR([comments])
)
```

`ATTR()` is a special Tableau aggregate that does the following:

```
IF MIN([Dimension]) = MAX([Dimension]) THEN 
[Dimension] ELSE * (a special version of Null) END
```

It’s really useful when building visualizations and you’re not sure of the level of detail of data and what’s being sent

**Note**: It can be significantly slower than `MIN()` or `MAX()` in large data sets, so once you get confident your results are accurate then you can switch to one of the other functions for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Try MIN([comments]) and make sure you have appropriate dimensions on your viz to partition the data fine enough to get a single comment for each combination of dimensions.